# Idle comet connections getting dropped

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet, long-polling

When using a comet technique such as long polling, if the long lived connection remains idle for some time, there's a chance that a NAT/firewall/loadbalancer/etc will drop the connection. Does TCP keepalive help in this case. Do browsers even set the TCP keepalive flag? How does the client/server even find out that a loadbalancer dropped the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your connection handling robust. I'm using cometd for my app, and you need to setup connection disconnection handling for that. I assume most would work this way. Your client will be able to know when a connection is dropped and reconnect/resubscribe to the channel. It's all described (for cometd) [here](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-javascript/subscription).

I'd recommend implementing something like cometd and watch the XHR requests in Firebug. You'll learn a lot about how it works (and feel a lot more comfortable with it as I did).